# Provide input file to CURL command

Tags: curl

I have the following curl command which works if I run it from the command line. As you can see, I am basically adding users test1, test2 and etc to some external server using rest call.

```
curl -i -H "Accept:appliaction/json" --user admin:admin \
--data "{'admin_id':'sec_master','admin_pwd':'password','commands': \
[ \
'user create -no-password-policy test1 uid=test1,dc=something,dc=com test1 
test1 password123', \
'user create -no-password-policy test2 uid=test2,dc=something,dc=com test2 
test2 password123'' \
]}" -k https://myhost/isam/pdadmin/
```

Since eventually I am going to add like over 100K users, is there a way provide an input file with the list of the users to curl?

Like maybe read this portion of it from a file?

```
--data "{'admin_id':'sec_master','admin_pwd':'password','commands': \
[ \
'user create -no-password-policy test1 uid=test1,dc=something,dc=com test1 
test1 password123', \
'user create -no-password-policy test2 uid=test2,dc=something,dc=com test2 
test2 password123'' \
]}"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `curl --data @users.json`, and put the JSON data you're posting into the `users.json` file.

Comment: Note that when you move your data into a file, you should remove all of the escaping that's only there for the shell.